# How to remove items in a list within a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have nested list `List<CarIds>` in a main list `List<MainObjectClass>`
And I created several use cases:

**Case #1:** CardIds contains at least one item 10001 and no other items

**Case #2:** CardIds contains at least one item 10001 and some other items (which needs to be deleted)

**Case #3:** CardIds does not contain at all item 10001 (ignore this MainObjectClass)

Note: There will be no case to duplicate 10001 twice or more times in a collection `CarIds`, it's unique number in that collection.

```
var response = new List<MainObjectClass>();

//Case #1
response.Add(new MainObjectClass
{
    Id = new Guid(),
    Name = "Test100Only",
    CarIds = new List<int>
        {
            10001
        }
});

//Case #2
response.Add(new MainObjectClass
{
    Id = new Guid(),
    Name = "Test100Only",
    CarIds = new List<int>
        {
            10001,
            5555,
            3
        }
});

//Case #3
response.Add(new MainObjectClass
{
    Id = new Guid(),
    Name = "Test100Only",
    CarIds = new List<int>
        {
            55558,
            55554
        }
});
```

I need to remove all MainObjectClass from List which don't have 10001 in a list of CarIds.

Also, if there any left other values in list CarIds I need to remove them (Case #2).

The final result for **Case #1** would be:

```
// Keep this object in List<MainObjectClass> 

{
    Id = new Guid(),
    Name = "Test100Only",
    CarIds = new List<int>
        {
            10001
        }
});
```

The final result for **Case #2** would be:

```
//Keep this object in List<MainObjectClass> and remove all items in CarIds **which not equals** to 10001
{
    Id = new Guid(),
    Name = "Test100Only",
    CarIds = new List<int>
        {
            10001           
        }
});
```

The final result for **Case #3** would be:
Remove object from List

What I tried:

```
response = response.RemoveAll(x => !x.CarIds.Any(y => y == 10001));
```

I tried somehow to inject another `.RemoveAll` before `.Any()` statement but with no luck.

Comment: "Note: There will be no case to duplicate 10001 twice or more times in a collection CarIds, it's unique number in that collection."
=> In this case, I'd recommend replacing the List with a HashSet for better performance: checking the existence of an item in a list requires browsing the list, whereas it's straightforward in the HashSet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want ?

```
response.RemoveAll(x => 
{
    x.CarIds.RemoveAll(id => id != 10001);
    return !x.CarIds.Any();
}
```